# Crystal Reports : passing parameters

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Reports in my asp.net application. I need to pass string as parameter to Crystal Reports that looks like :

**Samp**le Str**ing**

How can I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass Html to Crystal Reports. In your CR projects set param options as HTML, so you can see the param as html string with all its tags.